# Eclipse, packages disappaeared?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, maven

I rarely use complex IDEs (I favor simple editors and command-line tools) and my struggles with Eclipse have finally driven me into a corner I can't get out of. I don't even understand what happened, so I'll provide what details I feel are relevant -- feel free to ignore, or ask for more.

I installed Maven management for a Java project through m2eclipse, downloaded the indexes, installed some dependencies manually editing the `pom`, and...

... the package tree dissappeard from the left pane. The folders are still there, I can open all the files and edit them; the JRE library node is there, the Maven node is there, everything but the classical package/class tree.

I can still work by going through the folders, I guess, but many of the tools Eclipse provides (e.g. refactoring) are not available.

Help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, that the folders are not configured as source folders. Do you have the appropriate Maven folder structure, e.g. src/main/java, src/main/resources etc.? If so, then right click on the project and select "Update Project configuration" in the "Maven" sub menu. Then the project structure should be correct.

Comment: Fixed. The Update Project Configuration op did the trick. I'll try to remind myself that "there are no stupid questions" :P. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all the source folders in under /src.
The main doubt I have is you have probably messed up or worst, deleted some config file, either Maven specific (which I don't know) or eclipse specific. Note that there are many hidden/non-hidden files which are created by eclipse.

Also, try refreshing project and restarting the IDE. Seems trivial but sometimes works.